# Ravendb Array intersect

Tags: arrays, ravendb, intersect

I have a simple Raven dB table which is as follows:

```
char[] colorArray= colorValue.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray();

for loop{
var entity = new Color { ID = id, colorArray = colorArray };
session.Store(entity);
}
Session.Savechanges();
```

This table consists of 1000 or more records.

---

Now user inputs an array:

```
char[] userinput=userinput.tocharArray().Distinct().ToArray();
```

Suppose user's array consists of characters 'r', 'e' and 'd'.
I need to list all records which consists of all user inputted characters (i.e. the output records needs to have 'r', 'e' and 'd' characters).

I tried different techniques including following:

```
.Where(x=>x. colorArray.Intersect(userinput).Count()==userinput.count())
```

But not working, giving following error:
Cannot understand how to translate x.subsetArray.Intersect…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Array intersection is not allowed, but you can write your query as follows:

```
var colors = session.Query<Color>()
                    .Where(c =>
                            c.colorArray.Any(x => x == "r") &&
                            c.colorArray.Any(x => x == "e") &&
                            c.colorArray.Any(x => x == "d"));
```

Please note that in order for this to work, you need to use `string`s, not `char`s. The `colorArray` property in your `Color` class needs to be defined as:

```
public string[] colorArray { get; set; }
```

The reason is that if you use `char[]`, then the query will check for the numeric values (ASCII codes) rather then the string values (ex: `'r'` will be interpreted by the query engine as `114`, `'e'` to `101` and `'d'` to `100`).

Now, to take this to the next step and make the query condition dynamic, with respect to the `userInput` string array:

```
var userInput = new[] {"r", "e", "d"};

var colors = session.Query<Color>();

// dynamically add a WHERE clause for each letter in the array
foreach (var letter in userInput)
{
    var currentLetter = letter;

    colors = colors.Where(c => c.colorArray.Any(x => x == currentLetter));
}

// display the results
foreach (var color in colors)
    Console.WriteLine(color);
```

This should produce the results you expect: the documents that have `"r"`, `"e"` and `"d"` in their colorArray.